# NSArray's valueForKey: equivalent in PHP

Tags: php, objective-c, arrays, nsarray

In Objective-C there is `-[NSArray valueForKey:]`. But what is the equivalent in php? I would like something like this:

```
$things = [['name' => 'Frank', 'age' => 14],'name' => 'bob',['name' => 'Joe', 'age' => '85']];
$names = valueForKey($things, 'name');
```

I would like `$names` to be equal to this:

```
$names = ['Frank', 'Bob', 'Joe'];
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$things = array(array('name' => 'Frank', 'age' => 14),array('name' => 'bob'),array('name' => 'Joe', 'age' => '85'));
$names = array();
foreach ($things as $item) {
    foreach ($item as $key => $value) {
        if ($key == "name") {
            $names[] = $value;
        }
    }
}

print_r($names);
```

RESULT:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Frank
    [1] => bob
    [2] => Joe
)
```

RECURSIVE SOLUTION:
Using `array_walk_recursive` witch executes a callback function for every element in array.

```
function callback($item, $key){
    if ($key == "name") $names[] = $item;
}
array_walk_recursive($things, 'callback');

print_r($names);
```

RESULT:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Frank
    [1] => bob
    [2] => Joe
)
```

Comment: Ok Thanks, but is there a way to make it recursive and not only 2 levels deep?